# Reusability in iOS development

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been developing android app for last 4 years, and now shifted to iOS. Actually I am not shifted but it was a need of time, when My client wanted same version of my android app in iOS.

Now in android we can use Fragments, and we can use same fragment as many places in app as needed for same working.

So in iOS I know the container view can help me in same fashion. But what is more suitable for my current scenario

**I have made different ViewControllers for different classes, let say Class 5, class 6 , class 7. There are some changes in all ViewController and then they are showing list of Students in UItableView.**

That Tableview has same actions and same working from class 5 to class 10.I only need to change the data set for UITableview. Now I just want to do something like, "write once and use anywhere". I mean in android I could also do this in fragment and then can use it in anywhere it needed. But in iOS how can I achieve this functionality? Please help

Comment: To be honest, exactly the same way as on Android. Different framework does not mean you componentize implementation differently.

Comment: What did you just said? I did not understand?

Comment: Make a super class based on UIViewController and then sub-class that one and overwrite what you want to change. This is possible in obj-c and Swift. If you use IB, specify the sub-class for each scene.

Comment: @thomasgotzsche yes, I have seen some library doing this, but can you give me some example or tutorial link

Answer (score 0):

If the difference in all those controllers is just the datasource, I think you can just use single class (say Class 5). This is with assumption that the data required for all those view-controllers is of same type (e.h. Dictionary or your custom class)

Now, when you want to display the page 6 (for which you were earlier using Class6), just instantiate Class5, set the data property which is relevant to page6 and then finally push it in the navigation stack

P.S. In iOS, ViewControllers are equivalent of both Activity & Fragment in Android

Comment: This is whaat I thought earlier, but let me be more specified: Actually I have different  set of data. Let say for Class 5, I show some type of specialized design from top until the half of screen, and in other half I am showing UITableView, 

For each class I have separate ViewController, all view controller are divided into 2 half. Top half show some thing related to class and other half shows the list of students in UITableView. So now as list of students in all classes are of same data type , thats y In bottom half I just want to reuse something.

Comment: I hope now you understand. or for more simplicity, let me say for some reasons I cant use same ViewController for all classes. so now tell me the best way

Comment: Got it! You can achieve this by creating custom view classes for reusable views. e.g. You want use "view1" in all of the controllers, you can create class MyView extending from UIView, which will have its own XIB and own implementation in that class. Later, you can embed this in your view controllers

Comment: can you give me any example tutorial of that please?

Comment: https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960